# Centering menu on responsive site

Tags: css, menu, responsive-design, center

I got this site template and want to center the menu while it's not collapsed.
http://themes.iki-bir.com/kyte/index.html

**the html code is**:

```
div class="nav-collapse pull-right collapse"
```

**the css**:

```
#header.navbar {
padding: 25px 0;
background: #FFF;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
position: relative;
z-index: 1001;
width: 100%;
display: block;
position: fixed;
```

Hope that's enough..
Many, many thanks!

Oren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center the menu when its not collapsed, try this:

```
@media (min-width: 980px) {
    #header .container{  text-align:center; }
    #header.navbar-fixed-top .nav-collapse{ float:none;display:inline-block; }
}
```

The media query targets the menu only when its not collapsed, this media query could be already in your stylesheet since i see the template is using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
#header.navbar-fixed-top .nav-collapse {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 27px;
}
.navbar .nav {
    width: 715px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: Actually, this solution caused me some trouble when the menu collapsed.. thanks for your effort!